# PowerBuilder 12 and SQL bit data type problem (1 misread as -1)

Tags: sql, powerbuilder, bit

I have a PB 12 app that uses SNC to connect to a SQL 2008 DB. I have a table with bit data types that are filled in with 1s and 0s, as you would expect. When PB queries this table it converts all 1s to -1s. This is new behavior after we converted an old PB 9 app to 12, also switching our DB provider from OLEDB to SNC (SQL Native Client).

Digging around the web I see that this issue was reported back in PB 11 and that the only solution was to set a DBParm parameter to a legacy value that negatively impacts performance. (DBParm 'StaticBind' set to 0 instead of the default of 1).

Has there been any work done on this bug since then? How have folks addressed this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: to avoid issues when false can be expressed as 1 or -1 normally you check with if(value == 0) and whenever this check fails you know the bit has a non zeroed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most definitions of [boolean data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) (often represented as bit types in sql) state that 0 is false and non-zero is true. So in boolean terms -1 and +1 are broadly equivalent.

> In some languages, the Boolean data
>   type is defined to include more than
>   two truth values. For instance the ISO
>   SQL 1999 standard defined a Boolean
>   value as being either true, false, or
>   unknown (SQL null).

It could be that the -1 is returned in the query it is because PowerBuilder is interpreting the result as 'unknown' rather than 'true'.

So you should evaluate whether or not the value is 0 (false) and if not its true.

Comment: In essence, this is what I had to do in the datawindow in powerbuilder. I just changed the code to reflect a -1 being the 'true' value instead of 1. When the DW saves back to the SQL DB the value put in the table is still 1 because of Sql Native Client doing some conversion I suppose.